# "Temporary" folder

Tags: cron

I often download images, take screenhots, and save files that I am only going to use for a little until it can be discarded.

I want to create a folder which deletes the contents inside it every few days ad midnight to conserve space on my mac.

My original idea was to create a cron job to empty the folder at a specific time, but a problem exists.

My computer is a MacBook, and will not be powered on during the times that I want the files to disappear, this means I  need these files to delete when I power the device back on (or wake from sleep) given the time has expired.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple. Instead of creating a cron job, create a launchd plist (property list). Go to http://launched.zerowidth.com for help configuring common options and installing the plist. More options not included in the website can be found in the man page "launchd.plist" (by typing `man launchd.plist`), but you should be good to go with what's provided. The advantage is that `launchd` will run the plist when the computer turns on, if the computer was turned off at the time it was supposed to run. It'll even coalesce multiple events into a single event, if the script would have normally ran a few times while the computer was off.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want to create a cron job to empty the folder, it is a little intricate. I would also recommend creating a launched plist. It's efficient.